# Won't open runnable jar exported from eclipse Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javafx-8

I am running MacOS Big Sur (Intel MacBook Pro 2020) and I am using eclips for a college project.

The project is written with java and for GUI I am using JFX.

While using eclipse everything including the JavaFX code opens fine and runs.

When I am exporting the project to a runnable jar it asks to open it and then says there is an error .

On the other hand when my friends that are using windows are exporting to a runnable jar its working fine for them.

The project git is [Here to watch](https://github.com/raf545/Proj_GoNature.git)

I tried to run it throw terminal to see the problem and I get the following message:

```
 rafaelelkoby@MacBook-Pro ~ % java -jar Server.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:514)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:422)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:416)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:415)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 13 more
```

using java 8 JDK the JFX should be included so I can't really find the problem.

Comment: What does `java -version` give you? Because that stack trace contains module names, and modules didn't exist until Java 9.

Comment: rafaelelkoby@MacBook-Pro ~ % java -version
java version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: There you go. You're trying to execute the JAR with Java 15.0.1 which does not typically include JavaFX. You must have two or more versions of Java installed.

Comment: how do I do that ? is there a way to use java 8?

Comment: The "brute force" approach is to give the full path to Java 8 when executing the command instead of just `java`. At least that's an option on Windows. If you want Java 8 to be the default you'll have to research how to do that for MacOS (I only know Windows).

Answer (score 2):

So after the help From Slaw in the comments I figured out the problem and how to fix it.

My problem was that I was trying to execute a jar file using Java 15.0.1 witch doesn't work well with JavaFX.

At first check that you have Java 8 JDK installed.

And find the virtual machines folder witch in Mac is by default at the library folder under java folder.

Check you have a 1.8 version installed

Then check what is the java version executing the jar by the command:

```
java -version
```

Then if it is different then java 8 run the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

Then run again and check that you are using java 8

```
java -version
```

Check that it has changed and run you're jar by using

```
java -jar JarName.jar
```

If something is not clear please comment so I will change it.

Hope that I helped you :)

=======================================

Another option:

**If you're code is using java 8**

if the `java -version` is telling you that you are using something different then 1.8.X

On MacOS go to the virtual machine folder at
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

and keep only the 1.8.X you use so it will be the default.

worked for me as well